# How to track/fix a memory-related issue in a large C/C++ code on *nix systems

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks

What strategy you use while tracking a memory-related issue? What tools do you use (open source as well as proprietary) to identify memory leaks, memory corruption etc? How would you track memory leaks if only gdb/dbx available on a system?

For me, fixing memory leaks with only a debugger is very hard.

Comment: Personally I think this question is more programming related than unix related.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can change the source code, [Dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/) is great; it will list which pointers were unfreed and (for code built with debugging symbols) exactly which line they were allocated on.

If you can't, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is pretty much the standard for that sort of thing. I generally find Valgrind somewhat harder to use, but it has way more features and doesn't involve adding dmalloc calls into your code

Comment: dmalloc is not very performant as expected in very large systems. valgrind is a better bet, and even there you will hit bottlenecks...

Comment: valgrind --tool memcheck "yourapp" will give memory related info in runtime (useful in desktop systems). Another great tool is [memwatch](http://www.linkdata.se/sourcecode/memwatch/) but it should be compiled along with your source. Memwatch can log details to a file hence more suitable for embedded systems.

Answer (score 7):

valgrind is amazingly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) (from valgrind) is one of the best way to find memory leaks. Repeat your suspicious code (or run your program long enough) and dump the result with ms_print. Usually, the call stack is giving you enough information to fix it.

With GDB, you can try to attach to a running program and call functions such as `malloc_stats()`

If your program is written in a different language, it might be more tricky. Recently, some GDB has gained scriptability, and people started interesting projects such as [gdb-heap](https://fedorahosted.org/gdb-heap/wiki), which can analyze Python memory from a core dump. Similar memory analysys scripts might be possible for C++ objects.

Read also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564752/examining-c-c-heap-memory-statistics-in-gdb

Answer (score 1):

For Solaris, there's several tools listed in the answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881343/locate-bad-memory-access-on-solaris/) (they include leak checking with other forms of bad memory access).

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing Objective-C for some time, and there is an analyzer that deal with C level memory management and stuff like that. [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) is so good that Apple decided to bundle it with their xCode IDE. I'm not sure if this is good for your question, but if you are doing C then it's worth a try.

Comment: Minor quibble: clang was developed for use in xcode from the start. See http://clang.llvm.org/clang_video-05-25-2007.html

Comment: Hi Daniel, that might be true, but it wasn't included in xCode until recently (or at least not in the bundle I downloaded from Apple)